# Reading .xlsm macros file using POI does not work with VBAMacroReader and VBAMacroExtractor

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have downloaded latest version of Apache POI and trying to read a .xlsm file with no success using VBAMacroExtractor and VBAMacroReader mentioned in the link(http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html).Actually I don't want to do anything with macros,Just need to read the excel which has .xlsm extension and also write data.My condition is that I cannot remove the macros because of some business condition.Please suggest whether this approach is right.Also I tried using XSSF and HSSF format to read the excel file which gave errors.Please help.

Below is my sample code.

```
    VBAMacroReader reader = new VBAMacroReader(new File("MyMacroExcel.xlsm"));
    Map<String, String>  mymap = reader.readMacros();
    mymap.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println("Key:"+k+" Value:"+v));
    //  XSSFWorkbook nextWorkbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(myFile, true);

    VBAMacroExtractor extractor = new VBAMacroExtractor();
    extractor.extract(new File("MyMacroExcel.xlsm"), new File("Output.xlsm"));
```

The Code when I use XSSFWorkbook is below

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("Test.xlsm"));
    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
    System.out.println(workBook.getSheetAt(0));
```

StackTrace of the error is below:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.verifyZipHeader(ZipHelper.java:147)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:201)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:277)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186)
    at com.tandem.file.operation.ReadingCellData.main(ReadingCellData.java:28)

Comment: What errors you get? Please provide stack traces in your question.

Comment: I have added the code and stack trace above Axel. Please guide me.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Your `Test.xlsm` is not in `Office Open XML` format. But according the name `*.xlsm` it should be. What happens if you open this file using `Excel` and then resave it in `*.xlsm` format? Is `apache poi` then able opening it? If so, then the original file is in a corrupted file format somehow.

Comment: Perfect the file was in the corrupted state.Thank you for the help!!